# Hyperic HQ 5.0 Server is not running

Tags: cloud, monitoring, hyperic

**I have done below steps to install hyperic hq (5.0 open source) on ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit) machine, even i followed the steps mentioned everywhere , it still giving below error ( though commercial version installed correctly):**

```
Is there any can provide his comments ?

**[Step-1]**
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ$ sudo chown -R esumit:esumit /home/esumit/HQ
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ$ 
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ$ 

**[Step-2]**
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ$ ls
hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0  hyperic-hq-installer-x86-64-linux-5.0.0.tar.gz
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ$ cd HQ
bash: cd: HQ: No such file or directory
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ$ ls
hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0  hyperic-hq-installer-x86-64-linux-5.0.0.tar.gz
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ$ ls
hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0  hyperic-hq-installer-x86-64-linux-5.0.0.tar.gz
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ$ cd hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0/
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0$ ls
COPYING.txt                                 LICENSE.txt          setup.sh
hyperic-hq-agent-x86-64-linux-5.0.0.tar.gz  server-5.0.0.tar.gz
installer                                   setup.bat

**[Step-3]**
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0$ 
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0$ 
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0$ ./setup.sh -full
Unpacking JRE to temporary directory /tmp/jre
Please ignore references to missing tools.jar
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /tmp/lib/tools.jar
Loading taskdefs...
Taskdefs loaded
Initializing Hyperic HQ 5.0.0 Installation...
Choose which software to install:
1: Hyperic HQ Server
2: Hyperic HQ Agent
You may enter multiple choices, separated by commas.
1
HQ server installation path [default '/home/hyperic']:

What port should the HQ server's web-based GUI listen on for http communication? [default '7080']:

What port should the HQ server's web-based GUI listen on for secure https communication? [default '7443']:

Choices:
    1: Yes
    2: No
Would you like to use your own java keystore? [default '2']:

Enter the base URL for the HQ server's web-based GUI [default 'http://192.168.30.207:7080/']:

Enter the fully qualified domain name of the SMTP server that HQ will use to send email messages [default '192.168.30.207']:

Enter the email address that HQ will use as the sender for email messages [default 'hqadmin@168.30.207']:

Choices:
    1: HQ Built-in Database
    2: PostgreSQL
The HQ built-in database is provided for EVALUATION PURPOSES ONLY. For production purposes use vPosgreSQL. What backend database should the HQ server use? [default '1']:

What port should HQ's built-in database use? [default '9432']:

Choices:
    1: Yes
    2: No
Would you like to use an auto generated encryption key to encrypt the database password? [default '1']:

What should the username be for the initial admin user? [default 'hqadmin']:

What should the password be for the initial admin user?: 
(again): 
What should the email address be for the initial admin user? [default 'hqadmin@168.30.207']:

Loading install configuration...
Install configuration loaded.
Preparing to install...
Validating server install configuration...
Checking server webapp port...
Checking server secure webapp port...
Verifying admin user properties
Validating server DB configuration...
Installing the server...
Unpacking server to: /home/hyperic...
Creating server configuration files...
Using "small" installing profile...
Copying binaries and libraries to server installation...
Copying server configuration file...
Copying server db-upgrade files...
Copying server libs...
Setting up server database...

Now login to another terminal as root and execute this script:

    /home/esumit/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0/installer/data/hqdb/tune-os.sh

This script sets up the proper shared memory settings to run the
built-in database.

Press Enter after you run the script to continue this installation.


Setting up JDBC driver...
Copying database files...
Configuring database...
Loading taskdefs...
Taskdefs loaded
Starting repopulation of configuration table...
Starting built-in database...
Waiting for built-in database to start (on port 9432)...
Preparing database...
Loading taskdefs...
Taskdefs loaded
Loading taskdefs...
Taskdefs loaded
Loading taskdefs...
Taskdefs loaded
Waiting for server to stop...
Stopping built-in database...
Built-in database stopped.
Installing the server JRE ...
Unpacking JRE amd64-linux-1.6_33.tar.gz to: /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0...
Setting permissions on /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0...
Setting permissions on server binaries...
Fixing line endings on text files...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Installation Complete:
  Server successfully installed to: /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 You can now start your HQ server by running this command:

  /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/bin/hq-server.sh start

 Note that the first time the HQ server starts up it may take several minutes
 to initialize.  Subsequent startups will be much faster.

 Once the HQ server reports that it has successfully started, you can log in
 to your HQ server at: 

  http://192.168.30.207:7080/
  username: hqadmin
  password: sumit123

 To change your password, log in to the HQ server, click the "Administration"
 link, choose "List Users", then click on the "hqadmin" user.


Setup completed.
A copy of the output shown above has been saved to:
  /home/esumit/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0/installer/logs/hq-install.log

Deleting temporary JRE

**[Step-4]**
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0$ sudo /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/bin/hq-server.sh start
-e Starting HQ Server...

**[Step-5]**
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0$ sudo /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/bin/hq-server.sh status
HQ Server is running (PID:2814).
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0$ sudo /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/bin/hq-server.sh status
HQ Server is running (PID:2814).
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0$ sudo /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/bin/hq-server.sh status
HQ Server is running (PID:2814).

**[Step-6]**
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0$ sudo /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/bin/hq-server.sh status
HQ Server is running (PID:2814).

**[Step-7]**
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0$ sudo /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/bin/hq-server.sh status
**HQ Server is not running.**
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:~/HQ/hyperic-hq-installer-5.0.0$
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Hyperic documentation - 
 1. Hyperic server should be run as a non-root user.
 2. Hyperic agents can be run under root user.

Never run Hyperic server as root. If you do, stop it as root, run 'chown' command on entire Hyperic server dir to ensure all Hy[eric server files are owned by non-root user, and then start it up as non-root user.

And next time you run into Hyperic server issues, check the Wrapper log first. Wrapper log (wrapper.log) contains all the esential startup/bootup info. Server log (server.log) contains the regular operation info.

Answer (score 0):

All the steps of above are fine, What the mistake I did actually to start the server :

sudo /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/bin/hq-server.sh start

I used the command like : **(Without sudo)** /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/bin/hq-server.sh start

And it works

esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:/home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/logs$ sudo /home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/bin/hq-server.sh status
**HQ Server is running (PID:7374)**.
esumit@esumit-HVM-domU:/home/hyperic/server-5.0.0/logs$